# Pyspark: rearranging pyspark nested schema dynamically

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pypspark schema that looks like this

```
root
|--field1
|--field2
| |--element: struct
| | |--field01
| | |--field02
```

I need to recreate the dataframe schema to look like this:

```
root
|--field1
|--field2
| |--element: struct
| | |--field01
| | |--field02
|--newfield
| |--field1
|--newfield2
| |--field01
| |--field02
```

is there a way to do this efficiently in pyspark dynamically while keeping field1 at the top level as well? I have issues understanding how to parse and rearrange fields in pyspark and understanding struct fields. I tried exploding field2 with something like:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn("fieldNest", F.explode("field2")).select("*")
```

but even that, I only get the field2 field and couldn't bring the sub fields up to the top level. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want - some data types are missing in your schema, so I just guessed whether they are array/struct:

```
>>> df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- field1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- field2: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- field01: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- field02: integer (nullable = false)

>>> df2.withColumn('newfield1', F.struct(F.col('field1'))).withColumn('newfield2', F.col('field2')[0]).printSchema()
root
 |-- field1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- field2: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- field01: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- field02: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- newfield1: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- field1: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- newfield2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field01: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |-- field02: integer (nullable = false)
```

Comment: you guessed correctly on the schema almost to a T. This is what I'm looking for!